# Calling dism.exe from System.Diagnostics.Process Fails

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-server-2008-r2, system.diagnostics

For enabling Microsoft-Hyper-V and Microsoft-Hyper-V-Management in Windows 2008 R2 Server(64bit), I'm calling dism.exe as a process. The command I've used is

> Dism.exe /online /Get-FeatureInfo
> /FeatureName:Microsoft-Hyper-V
>
> Dism.exe /online /Get-FeatureInfo
> /FeatureName:Microsoft-Hyper-V-Management-Clients

This works fine when I execute this from the command line but it fails when I try to execute it through my code. I've tried the 64bit version of Dism.exe under the C:\Windows\SysWoW64 folder but it fails too. Here is the error message I get,

> You cannot service a running 64-bit
> operating system with a 32-bit version
> of DISM.  Please use the version of
> DISM that corresponds to your
> computer's architecture.

What am I missing here?

UPDATE: SLaks was right, but the issue turned out to be that MS Visual studio express edition by default targets x86 which I had to manually edit in the .csproj file to AnyCPU to make it work.

Comment: `SysWoW64` contains 32-bit stubs, not 64-bit executables.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Because you're running in a 32-bit process, you're [getting redirected to the 32-bit version in `SysWoW64`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Run `%WINDIR%\SysNative\dism.exe` to prevent redirection.

Comment: Tried it but still facing the same issue but no luck!
Here are two lines from the log,
_DISM.EXE: Executing command line: C:\Windows\SysWow64\dism.exe  /online /Get-FeatureInfo /FeatureName:Microsoft-Hyper-V_
_DISM Provider Store: PID=892 Loading Provider from location C:\Windows\System32\Dism\FolderProvider.dll - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider_
Although I've targeted the 64bit version of it, it's still looking up the 32bit processes' dism libraries

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me.  In my server (same OS, also 64 bit) there is no C:\Windows\SysNative folder at all...

Comment: The C:\Windows\SysNative folder is only visible to 32bit processes.

Answer (score 5):

Create below content in a batch file, for example RunDism.bat

```
%WINDIR%\SysNative\dism.exe
```

Call the batch file in your program. SysNative is not a real folder, so you cannot call above code in your program directly, it must be call by system. This way is worked for me.

Comment: I develop on Mac now so can't verify this but may be useful for someone else who faces this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The thing is you need to call the appropriate `dism.exe` dependng on the system architecture.

As @eric xu said, you need to resolve the path because it is not a real path. Below is the code that works for me. It basically detects the system architecture, resolves the path depending on the architecture and then calls the appropriate `dism.exe`.

```
string system32Directory = Path.Combine(Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%windir%"), "system32", "dism.exe");
if (Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem && !Environment.Is64BitProcess)
{
    // For 32-bit processes on 64-bit systems, %windir%\system32 folder
    // can only be accessed by specifying %windir%\sysnative folder.
    system32Directory = Path.Combine(Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%windir%"), "sysnative", "dism.exe");
}
```

Source: [File System Redirector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384187(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I had to use "SysNative\dism.exe"
If I added %WINDIR%\ it would fail, I'm using VS2017 installing on Server 2012R2.
Tnhx!