# How to use dism.exe in WiX ExePackage for IIS feature activation?

Tags: iis, wix

I have made a bootstrapper project with WiX 3.9.
In this project i install IIS Express and then i activate the IIS features.
Until now i added the Dism.exe from my computer as a resource and activated the features like that:

```
<ExePackage Id='IIS_WebserverRole'
            DisplayName='Installing IIS: IIS-WebServerRole'
            PerMachine='yes'
            SourceFile='.\Resources\Dism.exe'
            InstallCondition='SetupType="1" OR SetupType="3"'
            InstallCommand='/Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:IIS-WebServerRole'>
</ExePackage>
```

This works fine, but i think it would be better to use the Dism.exe which we can find in C:\Windows\System32\ on the computer to be installed and not a resource file from my own computer.
So i tried this:

```
<ExePackage Id='IIS_WebserverRole'
            DisplayName='Installing IIS: IIS-WebServerRole'
            PerMachine='yes'
            SourceFile='[SystemFolder]Dism.exe'
            InstallCondition='SetupType="1" OR SetupType="3"'
            InstallCommand='/Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:IIS-WebServerRole'>
</ExePackage>
```

[SystemFolder] is a Burn standard variable which returns per example "C:\Windows\System32\".
But this doesn't work.
So i tried the following one.
You can find it in the first answer of this article:

[Install IIS if not installed yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24439602/wix-burn-install-iis-if-not-yet-installed)

```
<ExePackage Id='IIS_WebserverRole'
            DisplayName='Installing IIS: IIS-WebServerRole'
            PerMachine='yes'
            SourceFile='.\Resources\run.bat'
            InstallCondition='SetupType="1" OR SetupType="3"'
            InstallCommand='Dism.exe /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:IIS-WebServerRole'>
</ExePackage>
```

But even this doesn't work.
I always get an error in the log file, that the executable file cannot be executed ;)

What's going wrong?
Can anybody give me a hint, what to do?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try changing this SourceFile='[SystemFolder]Dism.exe' to SourceFile='[SystemFolder]\Dism.exe'? Add back slash before exe name.

Answer (score 0):

Use `[System64Folder]dism.exe` instead

--- EDIT ---

https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/5307

As mentioned above, the directory that WiX points to with property `[SystemFolder]` has been updated.

Unless `[System64Folder]` is being used, in 64 bit operating system, `[SystemFolder]` will point to `C:\Windows\SysWow64` not `C:\Window\System32` where 64 bit version of dism.exe resides.

This question was asked before the change, but it was confusing to me when I arrived to this page, so thought it would be worth mentioning.

Comment: Can you expand on why this helps the OP? Short answers tend to be less useful than longer ones that have some explanation of how they're better.